# Authenticating API in R

Tags: r, api, authentication

I'm trying to access Bitfinex via api but struggling to properly authenticate my request. There is a Python example of what I want to do (https://gist.github.com/jordanbaucke/5812039) but I can't seem to get it to work in `R`.

```
key <- c("MY API KEY")
secret = c("MY API SECRET")

req <- GET("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/balances", 
               authenticate(key, secret))
               add_headers(X-BFX-APIKEY = key))
    stop_for_status(req)
    content(req)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/v1/balances` is a Bitfinex authenticated endpoints, thus it requires the `POST` request with a proper handling of `payload` and `headers`.

Here is a working example from my own script:

```
library(httr)

key <- "..."
secret <- "..."

# payload JSON object, the request should refer to the URL
# nonce should always be greater than for previous calls
payload_json <- list(request = '/v1/account_infos', nonce = as.character(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))))

# creating string from JSON payload
payload <- jsonlite::toJSON(payload_json, auto_unbox = TRUE)

# encoding payload string
payload_str <- base64enc::base64encode(charToRaw(as.character(payload)))

# adding three Bitfinex headers:
# X-BFX-APIKEY = key
# X-BFX-PAYLOAD = base64 encoded payload string
# X-BFX-SIGNATURE = sha384 encrypted payload string with the secret key
req <- POST("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos",
           add_headers('X-BFX-APIKEY' = key,
                       'X-BFX-PAYLOAD' = payload_str,
                       'X-BFX-SIGNATURE' = openssl::sha384(payload_str, key = secret))
           )

content(req)
```

For creating "New Order" you only need to change the `payload` to something, like this:

```
payload_json <- list(request = '/v1/account_infos',
  nonce = as.character(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))),
  symbol = 'BTCUSD',
  amount = '0.3',
  price = '1000',
  exchange = 'bitfinex',
  side = 'sell',
  type = 'exchange market'
)
```

The rest of the code will work without changes.

For list of `payload` parameters check the Bitfinex API docs, e.g. ["New Order"](https://bitfinex.readme.io/v1/reference#rest-auth-new-order).

Comment: Amazing thank you for sharing. Do you have an example for posting an order as well?